# Why is there more space on the bottom of the div?

Tags: html, css

I have a `header` with a `div` inside of it, for some reason there is more space under the `div` then above. I tried setting all the `padding` to `0` in hope to see which one was causing it but it seems to not be a `padding` at all.

[image]

HTML

```
<header>
    <div class="logo">
        <div class="centrDivInDiv">
            <h1>Welcome to Planet Earth</h1>
            <p>The best planet after Pluto.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

h1 {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

header {
    background-color: #E74C3C;
    padding: 10px;
}

header p {
    line-height: 0%;
}

.logo {
    line-height: 80%;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #2C3E50;
    display: inline-block;
}

.logo p {
    margin-top: 24px;
}

.centrDivInDiv {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0;
}
```

**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2j9dn614/1/)**

Comment: try .centrDivInDiv { display: block; }

Comment: @JustinBreiland that class is supposed to be used to something else (centering the text in the blue box)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:middle` to your `.logo` div (and you can remove it from `.centrDivInDiv`):

```
.logo {
    line-height: 80%;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #2C3E50;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2j9dn614/2/)

Answer (score 2):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2j9dn614/3/)

The problem exists because you're using `display: inline-block;` in `.logo`

The best way to solve this problem is to set **font-size** to **0** in **header** so it will be like this:

```
header {
    background-color: #E74C3C;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

Also you should set **font-size** in **.logo** so it will be like this

```
.logo {
    line-height: 80%;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #2C3E50;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Maybe this link will help you, it has more details

[Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements | CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is caused by the `display: inline-block` of your CSS. If you remove that or change it for `display: block`it will be fine. You should also set your `width: 50%`

All of that in your `.logo`

check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yerkopalma/2j9dn614/4/)